# How do you print out the input you put in?

Tags: python

I am writing a piece of code which asks for the users first name then second name and then their age but then i print it out but I'm not sure how to please give an answer.

```
print ("What is your first name?"),
firstName = input()
print ("What is you last name?"),
secondName = input()
print ("How old are you?")
age = input()

print ("So,  you're %r  %r and you're %r years old."), firstName, secondName, age
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to use string.format.

You use it like so:

```
print ("So, you're {} {} and you're {} years old.".format(firstName, secondName, age))
```

Or in Python 3.6 upwards, you can use the following shorthand:

```
print (f"So, you're {firstName} {secondName} and you're {age} years old.")
```

Comment: In Python 3.6: `print (f"So,  you're {firstName} {secondName} and you're {age} years old."`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
print ("So, you're %r  %r and you're %r years old." % (
    firstName, secondName, age))
```

You might want to consider using `%s` for the strings and `%d` for the number, though ;-)

Comment: wouldn't it be better to show the new format style?

Comment: Actually I don't prefer it, the old formatting is in no way deprecated, and OP's version was already closer to this.  But feel free to add your own answer using the new style.  (Oh, too late, Baldrickk beat you.)

Comment: I have to admit, I keep writing `%` style formatting in my code, as it's what I am used to.  For a new learner though, best to learn the current accepted style.

Comment: As I said, %-formatting is still "accepted" (we had that discussion here some weeks ago and found no deprecation note whatsoever).  The new formatting is just an alternative provided by newer Python version.

Answer (score 0):

New style string formatting in Python:

```
print("So, you're {} {} and you're {} years old.".format(firstName, secondName, age))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the fixed code:

```
firstName = input("What is your first name?")
secondName = input("What is you last name?")
age = input("How old are you?")

print ("So,  you're " + firstName + " " + secondName + " and you're " + age + " years old.")
```

It is pretty easy to understand, since this just uses concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to format the output string:

- **Old way**

  ```
  print("So, you're %s %s and you're %d years old." % (firstName, secondName, age)
  ```
- **New way (Preferred way)**

  ```
  print("So, you're {} {} and you're {} years old.".format(firstName, secondName, age))
  ```

The new way is much more flexible and provides neat little conveniences like giving placeholders an index. You can find all the differences and advantages here : [PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/)